# web picture is cropped in jframe

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane

The picture from a camera (accesible trhough direct IP address like "http://1111.11.11.1")
is croped ti fit my max screen size. I added a scrollbar, but it doesn't seem to have an affect. Maybe i need to implement them in a nother order, but i can't seem to find out how.
Here is the code and for reasons i can't give the camera IP, but i added a link to a rather big picture as demonstration.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class ShowWebPic {
    private static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://wallpoper.com/images/00/40/86/79/galaxies-nebulae_00408679.jpg");
            image = ImageIO.read(url);}
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        JLabel lblimage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        frame.addKeyListener(escape);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblimage, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.EAST);
        // frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.EAST); // tried this as well
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        }   //end of show

     private static KeyListener escape = new KeyAdapter() {
          @Override
          public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {frame.dispose();}}};
}
```

The code itself can be run independently and works... just not the way i need it to :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(lblimage, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
frame.getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

To:

```
//frame.getContentPane().add(lblimage, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(lblimage, // add image to scroll-pane!
    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
frame.getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```